# Ideal and factor ring

Tags: ring-theory

I want to determine the ideals and factor rings for $R\times\mathbb{Z}_{116}$ and $Q \times\mathbb{Z}_9$

I know that $Q$ and $R$ are fields and their ideals are ${0}$ and $Q / R$
and the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are $\{d\ast\mathbb{Z}_n : d \mid n\}$

I don't know how to work out the result.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything you need. Keep in mind that 
$$
A\times B\unlhd C\times D\iff A\unlhd C\wedge B\unlhd D
$$

Comment: I am sorry but i do not understand how to apply your answer to my problem.

Comment: @FrankD - 
For example the ideals of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ are the
Cartesian product of the ideals $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ such
as $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

Comment: Oh, ok. And for the factor ring?

Comment: @FrankD are you having trouble computing the factor ring of each ideal? Knowing all the ideals tells you all the factor rings...

Comment: So if the divisors of 9 are 1,3,9 then they are ideals of Z9 so i have (0,1) (0,3) and (0,9) ? and (Q,1) (Q,3) and (Q,9) ? Q being a field i don't think it would be a good way to write the answer. So can the answer be QxZ ,QxZ3 and QxZ9?

Comment: @FrankD - Yes, use the form with the $\times$